# Como configurar htaccess para reescribir o redireccionar URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Buenas tardes. Por favor, quien puede ayudarme con éste caso.
He creado un archivo .htaccess en el directorio raiz de un proyecto que he iniciado.
Estoy trabajando localmente. Instalé los recursos por separado. (Apache y PHP); es decir no usé aplicaciones como XAMPP, WAMPSERVER, etc.
Luego he colocado los siguientes parametros:
**RewriteEngine on
Options All -Index**
Según estuve leyendo, dichos parámetros me ayudan a evitar que aparezca un listado con todos los archivos y carpetas del proyecto cuando coloco localhost/nombredemiproyecto.
Sin embargo sí me los muestra como indica en la imagen
¿Qué puede estar sucediendo?

**Adicional**:

1. En httpd.conf habilité la siguiente linea:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

2. Y en Directory coloqué lo siguiente:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

A continuación detallo las instrucciones dentro de .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
Options All -Indexes
```

Quiero evitar que al colocar mi sitio web localmente, me muestre un listado de los archivos y carpetas